# Using node.js pool.query within pool.query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to create a pool.query where const Pool = require('pg').Pool. So I am able to connect and query without a problem, but I would like to query first to check the results and if the results.rowCount == 0 then I would like to make a new pool.query within the first query. However, I am getting throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set'); as an error.

I would like to do something like this:

```
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM complete_data WHERE data_date = $1", [date], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        if (results.rowCount == 0) {
            pool.query("SELECT * FROM complete_data WHERE data_date = $1", [date], (error, results) => {
            ...
        }

        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to send more than one response.

Try to change it to something like this:

```
 pool.query("SELECT * FROM complete_data WHERE data_date = $1", [date], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
                response.sendStatus(500);
            }
            if (results.rowCount == 0) {
                pool.query("SELECT * FROM complete_data WHERE data_date = $1", [date], (error, secondresults) => {
                ...
                response.status(200).json(secondresults.rows)
            }
        })
```